# Power up and down computers on a timer

Tags: power-management, windows-home-server

I've got a windows home server that's just great for backups and the like, but I'd like to reduce my power consumption.

What the best way to put it on a timer, say wake up daily at 6pm and shutdown if activity is less than 3% at 1am?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lights Out is a good option (as already suggested).

You may also like to try a program I recently wrote. It lets you hibernate and wake-up your PC according to configurable rules. I originally wrote it because I thought the full version of Lights Out was too expensive!

You can find it here: http://getsmartpower.co.uk

Comment: Looks very nice.

Answer (score 2):

[Lights Out](http://www.whsplus.com/2009/06/26/lightsout/) can sleep and wake the computer as demand changes or on a schedule.

Answer (score 0):

I know my Bios actually allows me to turn on/off the pc at certain times. For the less then 3% that is a bit more tricky. So far the only thing in my googling that turned anything up is [this](http://helpdeskgeek.com/free-tools-review/shutdown-computer-automatically/) program.

Answer (score 0):

Some BIOSes has that option to turn on computer at certain time.
You can use some other computer to WakeOnLan.